# R - Download Filtered Datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to be able to download a datatable after it is filtered using it's built in search. Either that or be able to filter a dataframe using the same kind of search used in a datatable and access the search on a datatable.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: @PorkChop I've tried looking for a way to access the internal structures of the datatable, and I've tried writing my own search for it, but it just doesn't work as good as the datatable search. The docs show no real way to provide filtering back to the server.

Comment: post the code with your attempts so we can have a look

Comment: @PorkChop Most of my attempts were reading the documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use client side processing, you can accomplish this with the input object `input[["tablename_rows_all"]]`. (append `_rows_all` to the name of the datatable output slot)

The `_rows_all` object will return the row indices of your data frame.  You can use that within your `downloadHandler` to subset the data frame when the download is initiated.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = 
    shinyUI(
      fluidPage(
        DT::dataTableOutput("dt"),

        p("Notice that the 'rows_all' attribute grabs the row indices of the data."),
        verbatimTextOutput("filtered_row"),


        downloadButton(outputId = "download_filtered",
                       label = "Download Filtered Data")
      )
    ),

  server = 
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
      output$dt <- 
        DT::renderDataTable(
          datatable(mtcars,
                    filter = "top"),
          server = FALSE
        )

      output$filtered_row <- 
        renderPrint({
          input[["dt_rows_all"]]
        })


      output$download_filtered <- 
        downloadHandler(
          filename = "Filtered Data.csv",
          content = function(file){
            write.csv(mtcars[input[["dt_rows_all"]], ],
                      file)
          }
        )
    })
)
```

Comment: i am trying to download a filtered data table using "d3tablefilter" ( Which allows for multiple strings to be filtered unlike Data table with filtering limitation )  . However replicating your code to download does not work . Can you please help ??  https://github.com/ThomasSiegmund/D3TableFilter