# Download filtered data from renderDataTable() in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to allow users to download filtered data from renderDataTable() in Shiny. In the MWE below, for instance, the user should be able to go to the "See Whole Data Table" tab and, say, select only values of "Blue" for Variable2. Then, they should be able to click the "Download the filtered data" button and see that filtered data.

However, as the code is below, when the user clicks on the "Download the filtered data" button, they download the entire (unfiltered) data. I have seen other examples (such as [R - Download Filtered Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597062/r-download-filtered-datatable)) and tried to incorporate them into my code, but remain stuck. Any advice would be so helpful. Thank you.

```
# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# Load data
data_table <- data.frame(Variable1 = sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace=TRUE), Variable2 = sample(c("Orange","Green","Blue","Pink"), 1000, replace=TRUE), Variable3 = sample(c("Square","Triangle","Circle"), 10000, replace=TRUE))

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", id="tabs",
    tabPanel("Column Summary", value=2,
       sidebarPanel(uiOutput("sidebar_summary")),
       verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
    tabPanel("See Whole Data Table", value=5,
       downloadButton('downLoadFilter',"Download the filtered data"),
       verbatimTextOutput("Raw"),
       DT::dataTableOutput('ex1'))
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$sidebar_summary <- renderUI({
    if (input$tabs == 2){
    print("This is a tab with information.")
    }
  })

  thedata <- reactive(data_table)

  output$Raw <- renderPrint({
    if(input$tabs == 5){
      output$ex1 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(thedata(), filter = 'top',escape = FALSE, options = list(pageLength = 10, scrollX='500px',autoWidth = TRUE)))
    }
  })

  output$downLoadFilter <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('Filtered data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep = '')
    },
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(thedata(),file)
    }
  )
}

# Create Shiny object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replicating the example from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597062/r-download-filtered-datatable) you provided it seems to work.

You just need to replace

```
output$downLoadFilter <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('Filtered data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep = '')
    },
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(thedata(),file)
    }
  )
```

in your server with

```
 output$downLoadFilter <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('Filtered data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep = '')
    },
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(thedata()[input[["ex1_rows_all"]], ],file)
    }
  )
```

That does the trick. Hope it helps!