# download the modified table in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to download the modified version of the table when I use the filter option in the table. Since the table is reactive based on the columns, only the chosen columns will be included in the downloaded dataset, however, every row is also included.

So for example, I choose 4 different columns and filter the dataset based on the columns and get only 2 rows. Is there a way to download this specific version of the table after the filter, instead of downloading the whole dataset?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        'input.dataset == "cars"',
        selectInput('col', ' ',choices = names(cars),multiple = TRUE,selected = c("price", "Mileage", "Cylinder")),
        
        downloadButton("download_cars", "Download data")

      )
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("cars",
                 DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"),
        )
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  car_data <- eventReactive(input$col, {
    
    df <- cars[, input$col, drop = FALSE]
    
    df
    
  })
  
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(car_data(), filter = "top", options = list(
      orderClasses = TRUE
      
    )
    )
  })
  
  output$download_car <- downloadHandler(
    
    filename = function() {paste("All_cars.csv",  Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")},
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(car_data(), file, row.names = FALSE)
      
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You need to set up a `dataTableProxy` to access the filtered version of `car_data()` that is <handwave=on>maintained by<handwave=off> `DT::datatable`

Comment: like this <https://stackoverflow.com/q/41597062/1100107>?